# How to response ajax request in Django

Tags: python, django

I have code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#error').hide();
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        var name = $("#name").val();
        if (name == "") {
            $("#error").show("slow");
            return false;
        }
        var pass = $("#password").val();
        if (pass == "") {
            $("#error").show("slow");
            return false;
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajax/",
            type: "POST",
            data: name,
            cache:false,
            success: function(resp){
                alert ("resp");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and view in Django:

```
def lat_ajax(request):
    if request.POST and request.is_ajax:
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        return HttpResponse(name)
    else :
        return render_to_response('ajax_test.html',locals())
```

Where is my mistake? I'm a beginner in Django, please help me.

Comment: what is the error message? behaviour? can you post your url.py?

Comment: csrf token ? Whats the error?

Comment: not "request.is_ajax", you need to call it "request.is_ajax()"

Answer (score 20):

Put `dataType: "json"` in the jquery call. The resp will be a javascript object.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/ajax/",
    type: "POST",
    data: name,
    cache:false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(resp){
        alert ("resp: "+resp.name);
    }
});
```

In Django, you must return a json-serialized dictionnary containing the data. The content_type must be `application/json`. In this case, the locals trick is not recommended because it is possible that some local variables can not be serialized in json. This wil raise an exception. Please also note that `is_ajax` is a function and must be called. In your case it will always be true. I would also test `request.method` rather than `request.POST`

```
import json
def lat_ajax(request):

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'name': name}), content_type="application/json")
    else :
        return render_to_response('ajax_test.html', locals())
```

---

UPDATE : As mentioned by Jurudocs, csrf_token can also be a cause I would ecommend to read : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

Answer (score 10):

how about create dict and parse to json:

```
name = request.POST.get('name')
dict = {'name':name}
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(dict), content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: my code still not work no response from django,.can you tell me referen to learn this?

Comment: there are lot of tutorials: 

http://webcloud.se/log/AJAX-in-Django-with-jQuery/

http://brack3t.com/ajax-and-django-views.html

http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jul/31/django-tips-simple-ajax-example-part-1/

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo:

```
    success: function(resp){
        alert ("resp");
    }
```

should be

```
        success: function(resp){
            alert (resp);
        }
```

Also, regarding csrf, you must use the header like this:

```
    $.ajax({
            url: "some-url",
            headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this...(Django 1.11)

```
from django.http.response import JsonResponse

return JsonResponse({'success':False, 'errorMsg':errorMsg})
```

When you process the json part in jQuery, do:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(returned, status, xhr) {
        var result = returned['success']; // this will be translated into 'true' in JS, not 'True' as string
        if (result) { 
            ...
        else {
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#error').hide();
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        var name = $("#name").val();
        if (name == "") {
            $("#error").show("slow");
            return false;
        }
        var pass = $("#password").val();
        if (pass == "") {
            $("#error").show("slow");
            return false;
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajax/",
            type: "POST",
            data: { 
                'name': name, 
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'
            }, 
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) { 
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(ts) { 
                alert(ts);
            }
        });
    });
});


def lat_ajax(request):
    if request.POST:
        name = request.POST['name']
        return HttpResponse(name)
    else :
        return render_to_response('ajax_test.html',locals())
```

Answer (score 0):

if nothing works, put "@csrf_exempt" before your function

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def lat_ajax(request):
"""
your code
"""
```