# Django datatables and multiple rows

Tags: django, datatables, django-templates, django-views

Good morning mates,
I am trying to pass some values to a view in Django.

I have a table (Datatables) with n values (id, name, lastname, etc), and I'd like to select some values and pass them (just the id) to the view and process it later.
I can select multiple values and it works properly:

```
$('#btnSelectedRows').on('click', function() {
          var tblData = table.rows('.selected').data();
          var tmpData;
          $.each(tblData, function(i, val) {
            tmpData = tblData[i];
            alert(tmpData);
          });
        })
```

The problem comes when I try to "tell" the view what values I want to process, I don't know how to send this values to the view.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You have to send ajax request to your view_func and process the response on client-side.
[example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642130/how-to-response-ajax-request-in-django#14642483)

Comment: Yes, you do. Json is almost standard way  for send information via ajax or api in web.

Comment: Thank you very much mate