# how to fix django error MultiValueDictKeyError

Tags: ajax, django, get

I am new to Django and I am trying to fetch data from the database into a dropdown list where i have 3 chained  dropdown list.

When I use `request.GET`, the system display the below error:

> raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
>   django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'cnt'

## traceback

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\LTGM~1\Desktop\TEST2F~1\test2\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py",
>   line 34, in inner
>       response = get_response(request)   File "C:\Users\LTGM~1\Desktop\TEST2F~1\test2\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
>   line 126, in _get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "C:\Users\LTGM~1\Desktop\TEST2F~1\test2\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
>   line 124, in _get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\LT GM\Desktop\test2ForImportExport\test2\testpro\views.py", line 23, in
>   getdetails
>       country_name = request.GET['cnt']   File "C:\Users\LTGM~1\Desktop\TEST2F~1\test2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py",
>   line 79, in **getitem**
>       raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key) django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'cnt' [21/Feb/2019
>   09:02:28] "GET /getdetails/ HTTP/1.1" 500 15859

## models.py

```
class country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class city(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.ForeignKey(country,on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):

        return str(self.name)

class road(models.Model):
    Vil = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city= models.ForeignKey(city,on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    country= models.ForeignKey(country,on_delete = models.SET_NULL,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Vil)
```

## urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home2),
    path('getdetails/', getdetails),
```

## home2.html

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                 $('select#selectcountries').change(function () {
                     var optionSelected = $(this).find("option:selected");
                     var valueSelected  = optionSelected.val();
                     var country_name   = optionSelected.text();


                     data = {'cnt' : country_name };
                 $.ajax('/getdetails',data,function(result){

                            console.log(result);
                            $("#selectcities option").remove();
                            for (var i = result.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                                $("#selectcities").append('<option>'+ result[i].name +'</option>');
                            };


                    });
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <select name="selectcountries" id="selectcountries">
        {% for item in countries %}
            <option val="{{ item.name }}"> {{ item.name }} </option>    
        {% endfor %}
        </select>   


        <select name ="selectcities" id="selectcities">


        </select>       

        <select name ="selectroads" id="selectroads">


        </select>



    </body>
</html>
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from testapp.models import *

import json as simplejson



def home2(request):
    countries = country.objects.all()
    print(countries)
    return render(request, 'home2.html',{'countries': countries})

def getdetails(request):

    country_name = request.GET['cnt'] # here is the error 
    print ("ajax country_name ", country_name)

    result_set = []
    all_cities = []

    answer = str(country_name[1:-1])
    print('answer = ' ,answer)
    selected_country = country.objects.get(name=answer)
    print ("selected country name ", selected_country)

    all_cities = selected_country.city_set.all()
    for city in all_cities:
        print ("city name", city.name)
        result_set.append({'name': city.name})

    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(result_set),content_type='application/json')
```

What I expect is that once the user select from the first dropdown list the second dropdown will display only the data that belong to the first selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you change your script as below and see if it works:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
             $('select#selectcountries').change(function () {
                 var optionSelected = $(this).find("option:selected");
                 var valueSelected  = optionSelected.val();
                 var country_name   = optionSelected.text();


                 data = {'cnt' : country_name };
                 $.ajax({
                     type:"GET",
                     url:'/getdetails',<--maybe a proper url is required leading to your view
                     data:JSON.stringify(data),
                     dataType: "json",
                     success:function(result){
                        console.log(result);
                        $("#selectcities option").remove();
                        for (var i = result.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                            $("#selectcities").append('<option>'+ result[i].name +'</option>');
                        };


                });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Your view:

```
 def getdetails(request):

    if request.method == 'GET' and request.is_ajax():
        country_name = request.GET.get('cnt',None) 
        print ("ajax country_name ", country_name)
        ............
    else:
        #return something
```

The error may be caused due to the data not being converted into JSON format. Maybe you need to change your view function after this.

Comment: Can you try using the answer submitted by @Shakil?

Comment: as you see i tried and it display this error :`answer = str(country_name[1:-1]) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Can you print the GET data 'country_name' and view the result it gives?

Comment: Can you check my edited answer and implement it? Maybe your url in the ajax query is not getting to the view.

Comment: i tied your answer  with keeping the django function ` country_name = request.GET['cnt']`   it display the error :  `raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key) django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'cnt'`

if change the django function into `country_name = request.GET.get('cnt', None) `

it display the error :  `answer = str(country_name[1:-1])
                               TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Can you tell the output of console.log(country_name) in your html template

Comment: it display in the console :

`[21/Feb/2019 11:30:20] "GET /getdetails?{%22cnt%22:%22%20Belgium%20%22} HTTP/1.1" 404 2215`

Comment: Check my edits. Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642130/how-to-response-ajax-request-in-django link for reference.

Comment: sorry for the late response  i checked your answer but still not working  and it display in the console this error:

`File "C:\Users\LT GM\Desktop\test2ForImportExport\test2\testpro\views.py", line 30, in getdetails
    answer = str(country_name[1:-1])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: NoneType means that the value is not being passed in the view.

Comment: it still display the error of `NoneType` and i did not know where is the error or how to fix it yet

Comment: I will have a look at it soon by testing this problem on my system. Then I think it would be a lot easier to find the problem

Comment: i comment this line ` data:JSON.stringify(data),` and it works   i am able to get the country name but still another problem appear i am not able to get the cities

Comment: What does console.log(result) give?

Comment: Try changing your HttpResponse to JsonResponse like `return JsonResponse(result_set, status=200)`. You need to import JsonResponse as: `from django.http import JsonResponse`.

Comment: i tried your last comment  this was the error :

`File "C:\Users\LTGM~1\Desktop\TEST2F~1\test2\lib\site-packages\django\http\response.py", line 552, in __init__
    'In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the '
TypeError: In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the safe parameter to False.
[22/Feb/2019 19:40:12] "GET /getdetails/?cnt=+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D9%86%D9%88%D8%A8+ HTTP/1.1" 500 15887`

Comment: to answer on the previous question about the log result it was  `<QuerySet []>`

Comment: In your view, does print(city.name) give the desired result?

Comment: Also post your models.

Comment: no the problem occurs before  this line....  the error is in this line 

`all_cities = selected_country.city_set.all()`

i will post my models.py

Comment: Output of print('answer = ' ,answer)?

Comment: the output of the answer is right and the `selected_country` is right

Comment: Well then maybe we need to try it in another way by using `all_cities=city.objects.filter(country=selected_country)`

Comment: i tried your comment and it display this error :

`File "C:\Users\LT GM\Desktop\test2ForImportExport\test2\testpro\views.py", line 36, in getdetails
    all_cities = city.objects.filter(country=selected_country)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'city' referenced before assignment
[25/Feb/2019 11:16:24] "GET /getdetails/?cnt=+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D9%86%D9%88%D8%A8+ HTTP/1.1" 500 15662`

Comment: city is your model right? Try to import the model and perform the action

Comment: i checked your answer as the right one thank you so if i want to make it for the third dropdown list it will be the same right?

Comment: Thank you. Yes that is what you need to do.

Comment: i tried to add a third dropdownlist but the system display **Not Found: /getRoads**

where **getRoads** is a function in views.py

Comment: Maybe the way you are calling the view is not correct.

Comment: can you help me in this question ?[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54881793/jquery-ajax-call-not-found-error-with-django?noredirect=1#comment96533817_54881793] (City matching query does not exist)

Comment: can you help me with this problem ?

how to display the selected data on the template ??
example:
selected country = 
selected city   = 
selected road =

Comment: Can't you just display the selected data using javaScript?

Comment: so its not possible to pass the variables from the view to template ??
as a dictionary using render ?

i usually send the variables using render but now with the httpresponse and json data i am not able to pass the variables also.

Answer (score 0):

seems like this is because `cnt` is not present in `GET` data. change this

```
 country_name = request.GET['cnt']
```

to

```
   country_name = request.GET.get('cnt', None)
```

And if you get `None` as country_name please add additional checking what you want to do in response.

Comment: when i try the add the .get i got the below error :

`   answer = str(country_name[1:-1])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`


but my question is why i get None  if the data already exist in the database ??

Comment: `cnt` is not passing, thats why it is none. Please kindly check the frontend or request api which is responsible to pass `cnt`.

Comment: what do you mean frontend or request api .... sorry i did not understand your comment.

its the only 2 files that i wrote the **html & javascript**   the **django function**

Comment: i added  the function that fetch the data from the table country

Comment: you code seems like from anywhere someone calling `getdetails` right ? who is response to pass `cnt` to that, from where you will get country_name as seems like cnt and country_name is same. That thing are not passing `cnt`, may be you are missing something. Are you sure , its `cnt` or it is `country_name` ?

Comment: if i understand your comment right you mean this :

` data = {'cnt' : country_name };` in javascript   where i send **cnt** with ajax in order to get it in the views.py function.

` country_name = request.GET.get('cnt', None) ` here where i am getting the send data  from **ajax** 
right ?

i will add the urls.py  to the question.

Comment: yes you are right. btw just before that can you console.log your country_name, seems like there country_name is none. Also from your code `$.ajax` this should changed to `$.ajax.get` or you can use @Sanip posted request. You are not sending any type.