# jQuery ajax call “Not Found” error with django

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, django

i have 3 dependent dropdownlists country city road.

where country is pre-populated from the database and based on the selection of the first the second will display the related cities.

i am able to select from the country list and it display the  related cities, but when i try to select the city and display the below error :

> Not Found: /getdetails2

how to fix this error  where **/getdetails2** is a function in views.py

## models.py

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country,on_delete=models.CASCADE , related_name = 'cities')



    def __str__(self):
        # return'id : {0} MouhafazatID :{1} Name :{2}'.format(self.id,self.MouhafazatID,self.name)
        return str(self.name)

class Road(models.Model):
    Vil = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city= models.ForeignKey(City,on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    city= models.ForeignKey(City,on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='roads')
    country= models.ForeignKey(Country,on_delete = models.SET_NULL,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Vil)
```

## home2.html

```
 $('select#selectcities').change(function () {
                 var optionSelected = $(this).find("option:selected");
                 var valueSelected  = optionSelected.val();
                 var city_name   = optionSelected.text();


                 data = {'ct' : city_name };

                 $.ajax({
                     type:"GET",
                     url:'/getdetails2',
                     // data:JSON.stringify(data),
                     data:data,
                     success:function(result){
                        console.log(result);
                        $("#selectroads option").remove();
                        for (var i = result.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                            $("#selectroads").append('<option>'+ result[i].Vil +'</option>');
                        };
                      },
                });
            }); 
        });
        </script>
```

## views.py

```
def getdetails2(request):
    if request.method == 'GET' and request.is_ajax():
        city_name = request.GET.get('ct', None) 
        print ("ajax city_name ", city_name)

        result_set = []
        all_roads = []

        answer = str(city_name[1:-1])
        print('answer = ' ,answer)
        selected_city = City.objects.get(name=answer)
        print ("selected city name ", selected_city)

        all_roads = selected_city.roads.all()
        print("roads are: " , all_cities)
        for road in all_roads:
            print ("road name", road.Vil)
            result_set.append({'name': road.Vil})

        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(result_set),content_type='application/json')
        # return JsonResponse(result_set,status = 200)

    else:
        return redirect('/')
```

Comment: show your urls.py

Comment: @MohitHarshan this was the error  i comment the path accidentally.

but now it display another error :

`return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LTGM~1\Desktop\TEST2F~1\test2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 399, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
testapp.models.City.DoesNotExist: City matching query does not exist.
[26/Feb/2019 11:09:52] "GET /getRoads/?ct=%D8%AC%D8%B2%D9%8A%D9%86 HTTP/1.1" 500 15904`

Comment: You print the data/answer given, do you really have a City object with that name? it tells you it cant find any with that name

Comment: @krs yes the name exist in the database

Comment: What is the output of the line `print('answer=', answer)`? Is it giving the proper output you want in string? Or is the output in another form?

Comment: the output of **answer** is different from the output of  **ajax city_name **

example:

`ajax city_name = milano
answer = ilan`